# Constructing an Email and Sending it Out

Tags: java, html, reactjs, email

Our frontend is using React with a Java backend. We wanted to allow users to be able to email information on the page to others. Looking around I can see that there are some people that use React as a template for emails, they'll generate the HTML and then send it to the backend (https://assertible.com/blog/creating-email-templates-with-react-components) (https://building.lang.ai/how-to-build-emails-with-react-fcf941b125d1), but I was wondering if this was the right approach.

Which approach would be better?

1. When email button is clicked, take the react component with props, convert to HTML and send to backend to be sent out. Outgoing json from the frontend would look like:

```
{ 
 to: <>,
 from: <>,
 subject: <>,
 body: <where the html would go>,
 additionalComments: <>
}
```

2. When email button is clicked we send will send the appropriate information from the frontend to the backend and the backend will generate the email. Outgoing json from the frontend would look like:

```
{
 to: <>,
 from: <>,
 subject: <>,
 foo: <>,
 bar: <>,
 additionalComments: <>
}
```

I'm leaning toward the first approach, but I'm not sure what is the standard. First approach would allow me to reuse the components I already have in React and use the backend simply as an email server. Second approach would allow us to persist more information and also eliminate the need to send html.

Comment: Have you considered a `mailto:` link? https://css-tricks.com/all-about-mailto-links/

Comment: We're trying to improve the look of our email so HTML and inline CSS would be required. `mailto:` links do not allow HTML or CSS tags, they'll simply render it as text. I am aware of a method using ActiveX but it's ActiveX so we don't want to touch that.